# Help! Cubic trigonometric Identity proof

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if anybody could help me find the answer to this question. In class we practiced solving trigonometric identities but no cubics. Then this question in one of my practice papers threw me.

$$\frac{\sin\theta-\sin^3\theta}{\cos^3\theta}\equiv \tan\theta$$

TIA for any help

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: i tried using the basic identities like $\cos^2\theta +\sin^2\theta \equiv 1$ , $\tan\theta \equiv \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ but thats all i was tought in class and i cant see how they fit in to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin\theta \left( 1-\sin^2\theta\right)}{\cos^3\theta}
=
\frac{\sin\theta \cos^2\theta }{\cos^3\theta}
=
\frac{\sin\theta }{\cos\theta}
=
\tan\theta
$$

Comment: thank you. sorry, can you please explain why we jumped from $\sin\theta (1-\sin^2\theta)$ to $\sin\theta\cos^2\theta$

Comment: @JamesBell consider one of the basic trig. identities involving sin squared and cos squared.

Comment: am i on the right lines? $\frac{\sin\theta -\sin^3\theta}{\cos^3\theta}$ $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta \equiv 1$ so $\cos^2\theta -1 \equiv \sin^2\theta$ so $\frac{\sin\theta-\sin\theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^3\theta}$ $\frac{\cos^2\theta -1}{\cos^3\theta}\equiv ?$

Comment: @JamesBell cos^2(theta)+sin^2(theta)=1 so 1-sin^2(theta)=cos^2(theta). This is what was used in the answer I posted. This relationship between sin^2 and cos^2 will come up time and time again. It is well worth being comfortable with it.